# Concatenar numeros em um arquivo csv python

Tags: python

eu estou com um problema em um arquivo CSV, pois eu tenho uma arquivo CSV com números de telefone, porem falta o número 55 na frente dos números. como eu posso está fazendo isso em python.

Esse é o meu código

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('telefones.xlsx')
df = xls.parse(sheetname="teste", index_col=None, na_values=['FONE1'])
colum = df["FONE1"]
colum.to_csv("NumerosBOT.csv", index=False, header=None, sep=',')
print(colum)
```

Exemplo da lista de números CSV

```
88992146288
84999697743
84999426811
84996022656
84996283916
84996566623
84996014057
84996331151
...
84999964363
```

E eu queria deixa todos nesse formato 55 84 9 99999999

Como seria feito isso?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
df["FONE1"] = df["FONE1"].apply(lambda x: '{0:5>13}'.format(x))
```